# How to configure GSuite user email signature by administrator

Tags: email, administration, google-workspace

I am the administrator of a gsuite domain, and I would like to configure email signatures for the users.

The problem is the users are not nearby, and so far the only way I found to do this is logging in as the user, which requires me to get the password from the user, get the google confirmation code to insert when trying to login or request the user to accept my connection if 2 factor authentication is enabled.

I would like, as an admin of the domain in gsuite, to be able to simply configure email signatures for all users. This is not a generic single signature for all emails, but I would like to configure them myself to make sure that they are coherent throughout all users.

Is there a way to do this from the gsuite administration area?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use an email signature manager that has native integration with G Suite. This way, you, as an account administrator, can create and manage [email signatures for G Suite](https://www.bybrand.io/integrations/gsuite) users, without personally going to each machine or submitting elaborate tutorials.

See the example of the Bybrand
[image]

Note in the example that Dr. Robert's email signature is updated in his professional Gmail account.

Now to have your software. I believe you or your business need to develop internally. Google doesn't provide a way to manage email subscriptions for all contributors.

- In G Suite settings, you have an option to set a disclaimer for all emails. But this is not a signature.